# Как обернуть адаптивный сайт в приложение?

Tags: мобильные-приложения

Доброго времени суток всем! Интересует следующее. Есть сайт с адаптивной версткой. Хочу просто обернуть его в приложение. Как это сделать? Вроде как есть такие возможности но нормального сервиса я пока что не нашел.

Comment: Cordova, например. Или вообще progressive web apps.

Answer (score 0):

[Phonegap/cordova](https://phonegap.com/) это решение для вас. Обернуть в приложение сможете за пару дней если же  у вас  PHP то я неуверен что это то что вы ищите только для статичных приложений.  Это обернет ваш  исходный код (html,js,css) в приложение то-есть тем кто скачал ваше приложение не нужно грузить статику с вашего хостинга а  он будет скачивать это в приложении а с сервером работать по API.
еще есть  https://electronjs.org/ но он также только для статичных сайтов

Сам пользовался  и тем и тем.  **Phonegap** понравился больше всего больше возможностей  и по скорости разработки и самой работы приложение хорошо себе показал.

Но имейте ввиду что это webview для крупного проекта стоит смотреть в сторон  native app

Comment: Нужно что бы онлайн работал. Что то вроде браузера только для одного единственного сайта и без всяких дополнительных элементов. Сайт динамический и изменения постоянные плюс на нем API карты яндекс используется.

Comment: такого не знаю обычно это работает толькот для сингл пейдж остальные просто бес смыслегы так как люди и так могут открыть ваш сайт  если вы не предлагаете нечего в приложнии для людей смысл его скачивать

Comment: да и аппстор такое не пустит  а гугл пустит но удалит через время

Comment: почитайте правила публикации приложений а скачивать через АПК люди не будут так как для этого нужно ити в настройки и ставить разрешение  на  установку со стороних источников

Comment: Phonegap или electronjs пускают в гугл и аппсторы потому что они работают без вашего сервера хоть както и то  если у вас будут проблемы  с сервером их удялят поэтому стоит сразу позаботится о стабильности приложения

Comment: Сайт предлагает карту определенных мест в городах. Приложение обертка для сайта нужна только что бы не нужно было открывать браузер так сказать упростить жизнь. Работать все должно только с интернетом. Таких приложений я видел не мало.